# Can we have enumerated or predefined annotations, which could be code-reused?

Tags: java, annotations

Let us define a annotation as below:

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface CheckSomething {
  String validIdentity() default "";
  String validUserGroup() default "google";
}
```

I have some set of annotations which is possible in my applicable and I would like to use them.

For example:

2 annotations below:

```
HumanCheckSomething, RobotCheckSomething - calling these for identification

@CheckSomething(validIdentity = "IAMSTRING", validUserGroup = "HUMANS")
@CheckSomething(validIdentify = "123", validUserGroup = "ROBOTS")
```

Now, I would like to create an enum using above annotations - HumanCheckSomething, RobotCheckSomething and reuse in my code, to annotate some methods.

```
@MyEnum.HumanCheckSomething
void allowOnlyHumans(){}

@MyEnum.RobotCheckSomething
void allowAll(){}
```

instead of

```
@CheckSomething(validIdentity = "IAMSTRING", validUserGroup = "HUMANS")
void allowOnlyHumans(){}

@CheckSomething(validIdentify = "123", validUserGroup = "ROBOTS")
void allowAll(){}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, that's not possible.

But many frameworks use "meta-annotations" to solve this problem: you define your own annotation (`CheckHuman`for example), which is itself annotated with the original annotation (`@CheckSomething(validIdentity = "IAMSTRING", validUserGroup = "HUMANS")` for example). Then, when you annotate some class (or field, or method, or whatever) with `@CheckHuman`, the framework does the same thing as if it was annotated directly with the original annotation.

See the Spring's [GetMapping annotation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/GetMapping.html), for example, which is a meta-annotation for `@RequestMapping(method=GET)`.

Another advantage of this pattern is that it allows combining several annotations in one. For example `@RestController` is a meta-annotation which combines `@Controller` and `@ResponseBody`.